# jQuery function filter with attribute name contains bracket is not working

Tags: jquery, filter

This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('[name^=foo]').filter('[name=foo\\[front\\]]').length);
  console.log($('[name^=bar]').filter('[name=bar\\[front\\]]').length);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo[front]" />
<input type="text" name="foo[front]" />
<input type="text" name="bar[front]" />
```

The first console.log return 2 as expected, but the second console.log return 0 which I supposed to be 1.  What's wrong with my filter selector?

Comment: Pass attribute value in quotes, then you won't need to escape `[]`. Use `.filter('[name="bar[front]"]').length);`

Comment: @Satpal According to [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) meta-characters must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\ so I don't think my code is incorrect

Comment: This is a valid bug..

Comment: I do not think it's a bug
the parser of selectors in jquery has no idea about the number of square brackets in attribute values, it wants to be informed of the beginning of the value of the attribute. The best way to do this is to add quotes around the value of the attribute in the selector.
that is, your code can be for example `<input name="]][[lololo[[[">` and this will be a valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Bug confirmed [jQuery Bug Tracker #4170](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3642)